# Linq query a List of objects containing a list of object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of foo called crepes. I want to return foo where `bar.doritos == "coolRanch"`

```
class foo
{
    List<bar> item;
    string candy;
    string beer;
}

class bar
{
    string doritos;
    string usb;
}

var item = crepes.item.Where(x => x.doritos == "coolRanch").FirstOrDefault();
```

From other threads, i've pieced together the above linq query, but crepes.item throws an error. "List does not contain a definition for 'item' and no definition for 'item' accepting first argument...

Comment: Fields in `C#` are *private by default*. Change your declaration to `public List<bar> item;`

Comment: both the class and the prop are public. Still getting the error, is my linq correct?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Given that crepes is a `List<Foo>`, you need to add an additional level to the linq query.

```
var item = crepes.Where(a => a.item.Any(x => x.doritos == "coolRanch")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `item` [access modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) is `private` (this is C# default for `class`), it should be made `public`

This goes for your `doritos` too

Also, since your `crepes` is a `List`, put additional layer of LINQ (as also suggested by others) to completely fix it, something like this

```
var item = crepes.Where(f => f.item.Any(b => b.doritos == "coolRanch")).FirstOrDefault(); //f is of foo type, b is of bar type
```

Comment: both the class and the prop are public. Still getting the error, is my linq correct?

Comment: @Chris  What error does it produce now? I think you should change your `doritos` too

Answer (score 2):

If you fix your classes like this

```
class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> Items { get; set; }
    public string Candy { get; set; }
    public string Beer { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public string Doritos { get; set; }
    public string Usb { get; set; }
}
```

Your query will look like

```
var crepes = new List<Foo>();
var item = crepes.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Items.Any(b => b.Doritos == "coolRanch"));
```

Here, we are trying to get the first `Foo` which has at least one `Bar` in `Items` where `Doritos == "coolRanch"`.