# Calculation on List<> subset with Linq Skip and Take

Tags: c#, linq, average

As according to this stack question: [How to calculate the rolling average of a C# array list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862081/how-to-calculate-the-rolling-average-of-a-c-sharp-array-list)

You can take a running average of values in a normal list like this:

```
List<int> numlist = new List<int>();
List<double> averages = Enumerable.Range(0, numlist.Count - 3).
                          Select(i => numlist.Skip(i).Take(4).Average()).
                          ToList();
```

My Question: I want to be able to do that on ***a specific subset*** of a class list:

```
public class Data_Raw
{
    public DateTime DateDataRaw { set; get; }
    public double PriceRaw { set; get; }
    public double PercentageReturnsRaw { set; get; }

    public Data_Raw(DateTime _dateDataRaw,double _priceRaw, double _percentageReturnsRaw)
    {
        DateDataRaw = _dateDataRaw;                     //1
        PriceRaw = _priceRaw;
        PercentageReturnsRaw = _percentageReturnsRaw;
    }
}

List<Data_Raw> myRawData = new List<Data_Raw>();
```

I want to calculate the average of the `PriceRaw` data, within the class list which is `myRawData`.

EDIT:

If this is the data for `PriceRaw`:

```
myRawData[0].PriceRaw=2
myRawData[1].PriceRaw=3
myRawData[2].PriceRaw=4
myRawData[3].PriceRaw=5
```

How do I get the average value of the last three `PriceRaw` values which is = (3+4+5)/3 = 4. It is only available directly after `myRawData.Skip`

Skip is not available if I try to append it to `myRawData[].PriceRaw.Skip`

This stack question gets me closer, but can't figure it out: [Linq query a List of objects containing a list of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532572/linq-query-a-list-of-objects-containing-a-list-of-object/34532641)

Comment: So what is the issue?  Why don't you do it in the way you talked about at the top?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] **including sample data**, and specify the **exact results** you are wanting to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply select the value you need into your `numList` (see first line):

```
var numList = myRawData.Select(x => x.PriceRaw).ToList();
List<double> averages = Enumerable.Range(0, numlist.Count - 3).
                      Select(i => numlist.Skip(i).Take(4).Average()).
                      ToList();
```

An alternate way could be this:

```
List<double> averages = Enumerable.Range(0, myRawData.Count - 3).
                      Select(i => myRawData.Skip(i).Take(4).Select(x => x.PriceRaw).Average()).
                      ToList();
```

Comment: thanks I will see to read a tutorial, however your example does not work..

Comment: Sorry, fixed that

Comment: that just defeats the purpose of having a class list that holds all your data, vs several normal lists...  it breaks the class list down to access the data

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier for you to manage it if you use comprehension syntax. ie:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Data_Raw> myRawData = new List<Data_Raw> {
       new Data_Raw(new DateTime(2018,1,1), 2, 1),
       new Data_Raw(new DateTime(2018,1,2), 3, 1),
       new Data_Raw(new DateTime(2018,1,3), 4, 1),
       new Data_Raw(new DateTime(2018,1,4), 5, 1),
       new Data_Raw(new DateTime(2018,1,5), 6, 1),
       new Data_Raw(new DateTime(2018,1,6), 7, 1),
       new Data_Raw(new DateTime(2018,1,7), 8, 1),
    };

    var groupSize = 3;
    var result = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, myRawData.Count() - (groupSize - 1))
                 let myGroup = myRawData.Skip(i).Take(groupSize)
                 select new
                 {
                     Values = string.Join(",", myGroup.Select(rd => rd.PriceRaw.ToString())),
                     Average = myGroup.Average(rd => rd.PriceRaw)
                 };
}

public class Data_Raw
{
    public DateTime DateDataRaw { set; get; }
    public double PriceRaw { set; get; }
    public double PercentageReturnsRaw { set; get; }

    public Data_Raw(DateTime _dateDataRaw, double _priceRaw, double _percentageReturnsRaw)
    {
        DateDataRaw = _dateDataRaw;                     //1
        PriceRaw = _priceRaw;
        PercentageReturnsRaw = _percentageReturnsRaw;
    }
}
```